# how do i count two values in single row in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table with two columns company and description with the following details

```
company         decription
a               welding,plumbing
b                 welding
c                plumbing
d                welding,plumbing
e                welding plumbing
f                 plumbing
```

how do i get a count of the companies  with the description of both  welding And plumbing

Comment: This is a **broken** schema design. **NEVER** put comma-separated data into a column. At least, not if you expect to query it in a reasonable way with reasonable performance.

Comment: ok thanks, noted. the dataset is a dirty dataset i was practicing on  by  trying to clean it. but hypothetically if you recieve a dataset similar to this in a real world situation what do you do? since it has a broken schema design, do you reject it?

Comment: When you talk about receiving a dataset, you're usually in some kind of **ETL process** (export, transform, load) process, where the "export" was processed out of your control. But you still have the ability to _transform_ the data into something more acceptable before loading it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIKE` to check for both terms.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM your_table
WHERE LOWER(decription) LIKE '%welding%'
  AND LOWER(decription) LIKE '%plumbing%'
```

Comment: Will work fine, as long as no swelding or splumbing show up. (Or similar.)

Comment: True true, @Richa did not give a lot of explanation about his data though :).

Comment: its just a dirty dataset i was using to practice on data cleaning in sql. thanks for the answer you provided, but it still didnt solve it